# Using Ransack in rails for searching companies and associated categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a search feature in my app where I search for a company and the results are companies fitting the name and the associated primary_categories for all of those companies.

I'm using ransack to grab the relevant companies.

Companies and PrimaryCategories have a has_many_and_belongs_to_many association. I'm refactoring the code to grab relevant primary categories from returned companies.

Below is the method before the changes.

```
def search
  @q = Company.ransack(name_cont: params[:q][:name], keywords_name_cont: params[:q][:name], m: 'or')
  @companies = @q.result.uniq
  @q2 = PrimaryCategory.ransack(name_cont: params[:q][:name])
  @categories = @q2.result.uniq
  @search_term = params[:q][:name]
end
```

On the search results page, I can retrieve the company but the primary categories are blank since I'm being returned an empty array object.

I'm looking for a clean way to extract the associated primary_categories from the returned companies

I've re-written the above method to include an array object.

```
def search
  @q = Company.ransack(name_cont: params[:q][:name], keywords_name_cont: params[:q][:name], m: 'or')
  @companies = @q.result.uniq
  @categories = []
  @search_categories = @companies.each {|co| @categories << co.primary_categories}
  @categories.flatten!.uniq
  @search_term = params[:q][:name]
end
```

This works but I want to know if I can get the same result using ransack. Is there a more efficient way to grab the associated objects using ransack instead of creating a separate categories array?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to get here. are you trying to load two types of models in the same search action or are you trying to search by name or category?

Answer (score 0):

For your initial question of loading companies based on name and including the categories with the companies I would just use the includes ActiveRecord option.

`Company.includes(:primary_categories).ransack(...)`

each company loaded will then have its primary_categories eager loaded.